# Jpa id generation strategy, @id default is auto , mysql default is IDENTITY, but I found that a hibernate_sequence table was generated, why?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Jpa id generation strategy, @id  default is  auto , mysql default  is IDENTITY, but I found that a hibernate_sequence table was generated, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs when 'combining' Hibernate 5 and MySQL. See [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/) to read more about this.

Use the following mapping to solve this.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 0):

auto strategy ,hibernate 4  is identity , 5 is table

Answer (score 0):

You can do that
application.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with mostly code, please explain your answer a little bit. In this case, there are more answers, so try to show the advantages of yours.